# ColdFusion/Mach-II Unable to load/find base config file upon initial load of site

Tags: coldfusion, mach-ii

Internal/Intranet application

IIS Error:

```
Unable to find the base config file for module ''.configPath=D:\Sites\xxx\webroot\config\mach-ii.xml 
The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\Sites\xxx\webroot\Index.cfm, line: 131
```

Experiencing some errors when initially loading my MachII site within a browser.  The server returns a 500 error because it can't find the page being requested.

Yet when you manually refresh the site, it then goes to the page as expected.

A recent code change was put in to Authenticate the user:

```
    <cfif CGI.REMOTE_USER EQ "">
      <cfheader name="WWW-Authenticate" value="NTLM" />
      <cfheader statuscode="401" statustext="Not Authorized" />
      <cfabort />
    </cfif>
```

So I suspect this may have something to do with the actually error.  I'm just trying to figure out some kind of link between the two.  BTW (The above code was put in to force the user to authenticate themselves and to populate the CGI.REMOTE_USER variable) which by default is not populated unless they are authenticated.

Also, once the application is run once, it's good for the rest of the working day (or for an extended period of time).  Shut down, re-load browser and navigating to any area on the site works just fine. It's just the initial load of the site that causes this error to occur.

Comment: Can you show us the line in your Application.cfc where you set the MACHII_CONFIG_PATH variable?